# Fullscreen video div does not show on mobile

Tags: html, css, video

I am having an issue with fullscreen videos on mobile devices. The code below works great on desktop and even in Chrome tools mobile mode. For some reason when you actually load it on a mobile device it's a white screen. [See this pen.](https://codepen.io/dogcats/pen/GRPqWNW)

```
<div id='holderDiv'>
  <video id="video2" loop muted class='background-video'>
  <source src="https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-5s.mp4#t=o.1" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>



#holderDiv {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  width:100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  z-index: 100;  
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;  
}
.background-video{
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  width:100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 1500;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
I think it has something to do with autoplay in mobile phones.
If I remember correctly regular `autoplay` doesn't work well in mobiles.

```
<div id='holderDiv'>
 <video id="video2" 
   autoplay
   muted 
   playsinline
   preload
   loop
   onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true" 
   oncanplay="playVideo(this)" 
   onended="playVideo(this)"
   class='background-video'>

  <source src="https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-5s.mp4#t=o.1" type="video/mp4" />

 </video>
</div>
```

Comment: This did it! Specifically it was just the playsinline property that fixed everything.